# APNS server in .net to get push notification

Tags: ios, .net, apple-push-notifications

Can you please suggest any APNS server in .net to get push notification.

Currently I'm using Moon APNS for iOS push notifications and facing strange error. If we invoke web-service on local computer to send push notification, everything works fine. But, when we publish this code to our testing/Live server, push notifications are not delivered to the phone, but the code is exactly the same!

Error log for more detail.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q48Qa.png)